# android jetpack compose: ACTION_UP only reached for tap but not after ACTION_MOVE when using pointerInteropFilter

Tags: pointers, input, android-jetpack-compose, action, motionevent

I need to scroll programatically (in order to snap items to adjust symmetrically top and bottom) after scrolling or after a tap (click) in a lazy column. I also need to start at a specific item when app launches - starts.

I am using pointerInteropFilter to be able to run some code at these actions: down, move, up. The code runs ok when I tap but it does not trigger ACTION_UP after a move is done.

[this is the desired result as soon as I release the finger from the screen... that is... a "jump" or scroll to a value that in this cases is item 10 and some offset][1]

The code is working only for tap... but the coroutine is not working when Action_up

I read that we are adviced to "prefer pointerInput] and use this only for interoperation with

- existing code that consumes [MotionEvent]s"

It also say that pointerinteropFilter try to make a seamless treatment between view and motion events... but I dont know if it is relevant.

Thanks.

Mauricio

````
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val listState2 = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState2,
    ) {
        items (50) {index ->
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .pointerInteropFilter {

                            when (it.action) {
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                                    Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "down pressed")
                                    false
                                }
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                                    Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "moved done")
                                    false
                                }

                                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                                    coroutineScope.launch {
                                        listState2.scrollToItem(10, 28)
                                    }
                                    Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "up detected")
                                }

                                MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                                    coroutineScope.launch {
                                        listState2.scrollToItem(10, 28)
                                    }
                                    Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "canceled chosen")
                                    false
                                }

                                else ->
                                    false
                            }
                            true
                        },
                    text = "item $index",
                )
        }
    }
}```




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSiCG.png
````

Comment: Forgot to say that I tried flagging FALSE for the parent (lazycolumn) to try to avoid it consuming the event... But it did not change the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issues.

The `onClick=` function doesn't work for all descendants, that are placed in the same composable ConstraintLayout, if the layout uses `.pointerInteropFilter` and returns true as a result of catching `ACTION_UP`  MotionEvent.

It's related to the fact that clickable logic under the hood expects `PressInteraction.Press` which value is a simple mapping from `ACTION_UP`. Thus ConstraintLayout by catching `ACTION_UP` MoutionEvent prevents passing of `PressInteraction.Press` to descendants.

If the ConstraintLayout will return false on `ACTION_UP` MoutionEvent, then the next MotionEvents won't be dispatched to it next time. Because of implementation under the hood.

So the root cause of the issue is misusing of the  `Modifier.pointerInteropFilter`. The idea behind the function is filtering events, what it actually does.

In my case looks like it's required to rewrite Touch logic to `Modifier.pointerInput`.

Maybe this findings will help you as well